# Do I need a SWR meter for a basic 2 meter antenna?

Tags: antenna, antenna-construction, ht, swr-meter

I have a 5 watt 2 meter handheld transceiver and want to build a helmet with an antenna, microphone (with VOX enabled) and earpiece for the radio. For the antenna part, I just want to do something simple like a wire at the right length. I'm 15 and saving for so much other stuff (like a signal generator, bench power supply etc.) and can't really afford an SWR meter.

Comment: You might want to look at hamfests and online auction sites; it should be possible to find a 144 MHz SWR meter pretty cheaply. Same for the other equipment you mention that you are saving for.

Comment: Be sure to put a propeller at the top.  Made of something non-conductive, of course.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At power levels that low, you probably don't need an SWR meter permanently installed. You will find it useful to have an SWR meter or antenna analyzer available when building the antenna, though, to ensure it is properly operating on your chosen frequencies. Perhaps you can borrow one from a friend, mentor, or local radio club to use while building your kit?